# webview can't popup softinput on android 4.2.2

Tags: android, webview

My `HtmlActivity` contains webview, progressbar. The webview and progressbar comes from a `layout.xml file`. In some other devices except android 4.2.2 platfrom, webview works well, after clicked an input box. The `inputmethod` is pop-up well.

Here is my `layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:title="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.vstar.widget.TitleView
        android:id="@+id/html_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:background="?attr/theme_base_title_style"
        title:titleViewHomeBackground="?attr/theme_title_back_image"
        title:titleViewHomeText="?attr/theme_title_back_text"
        title:titleViewMenuBackground="?attr/theme_title_more_image"
        title:titleViewMenuPaddBottom="?attr/base_title_padd_bottom"
        title:titleViewMenuPaddTop="?attr/base_title_padd_bottom"
        title:titleViewMenuText="?attr/theme_title_more_text"
        title:titleViewTitleBackground="?attr/theme_title_more_text" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/html_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:max="100" />

    <com.vstar.widget.ScrollWebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:background="?attr/theme_html_bottom_background" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/html_menu_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_half"
            android:background="@drawable/base_selector_html_bottom_back" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/html_menu_forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_half"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/html_menu_back"
            android:background="@drawable/base_selector_html_bottom_forward" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/html_menu_stop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_half"
            android:background="@drawable/base_selector_html_bottom_stop" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be great.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. Change `com.vstar.widget.ScrollWebView` to `WebView`, it works well. But i still don't the reason.